# Meaning of "They don't have alibis" in "The Intuitionist"

Tags: meaning, the-intuitionist, colson-whitehead

> The traffic at quitting time is a bother. Radio station WCAM equips
> men with binoculars and positions them at strategic overpasses to
> describe the gnarls and tangles. Lila Mae is never able to
> differentiate these men from the meandering isolates who linger at the
> margins of freeways. All of them make obscure, furtive gestures, all
> share a certain stooped posture that says they lack substantive
> reasons for being where they are, at the side of the road. Impossible
> to distinguish a walkie-talkie from a bottle of cheap wine at such
> distances.
>
> **They don't have alibis**, Lila Mae appraises the men at the
> side of the road.

This is from *The Intuitionist* by Colson Whitehead. I don't understand what does alibi mean in this context.
You can see some more text [here](https://archive.nytimes.com/www.nytimes.com/books/first/w/whitehead-intuitionist.html).

Comment: It's clear from the extract that Lila Mae has some eccentric ideas and the book's world-view is off-kilter and intentionally quirky. Which makes it hard to answer. It could just mean they look guilty (someone who has an alibi is innocent).